# Looking for a pattern for class creation & configuration based on input params

Tags: java, design-patterns, command-pattern

I need to create a complex configuration object based on the values of params I receive.

My inputs are 2 simple variables, and a configuration object. The combination of the 2 variables, and the config object's internals will determine the configuration of the output class (which is always the same type)

Doing this with simple if-else it'd look like this:

```
if (a == 1 && b == 1) {
//do some testing on the input object, configure and return the output object
else if (a == 2 && b == 1) {
//do some different testing on the input, configure and return the output.
}
```

and on.

There are about 5 different values that a & b could hold and depending on the values of a & b, I'm going to have to test for different things within the input object.

I'm not really sure of the best way to solve this. 
My first thought is to have some kind of `Command Pattern` with a method like:

```
public interface Command {
  public OutputConfig execute(InputConfig config);
}
```

and store my potential a & b combinations in `Map<Pair<A,B>, Command>` for lookup.

I feel like I'm looking for some Factory / Command / Builder pattern but not sure of the best way to implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are A, B in the Pair?

Comment: @arjacsoh Enum values

Comment: If there are only five different cases you need to cover (if i've understood that correctly), i would probably just hardcode the tests. You can make the decision more elegant and regular by introducting an abstraction like a map, but at the cost of increased complexity. I wouldn't pay that cost until the sheer number of cases, or a need to add cases at runtime, made the hardcoded case unacceptable.

Comment: @TomAnderson If it was just 5 I'd agree - sadly it's more like 15-25, which is going to make it a little less manageable.

Comment: Yeah, that seems like enough to be too many. The cut-off is probably at the good old "seven plus or minus two"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the `Strategy Pattern`. You define an interface with a method:

```
interface Configure{

public YourObject excecute(YourObject o);

}
```

You implement the interface in the variety of ways you want and you declare it as a member field. Then you instantiate the appropriate class according to the values of the variables.

If you want to save the Objects then you can use the `Command Pattern` as well.

**Update:** Ok in Software Enginneering there is usually no absolute truth.

With the `Command Pattern` you have already a class that does some tasks and you want to save them as Objects from a class deriving from an interface, in order to use them later etc. I do not reckon that your case requires such an approach, since you need merely diverse functionalities defined as an interface method. `Strategy Pattern` is therefore in your case a more elegant approach.

Comment: Could you explain how this differs from my execute() method above - maybe I wasn't being explicit enough, so I've added an interface declaration above the method declaration - I'm failing to see how yours adds to mine.

Answer (score 0):

To make it generic you need factory pattern. Strategy pattern helps if method signatures remain the same or you have access to required objects from within the enum. Factory pattern on the other hand is about obtaining different implementation within your main code.